# Getting transformed parameter into `esttab`

Tags: stata

I estimate a model and want to impose some restrictions on the parameters, which I achieve by using transformed variables, as described [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/linear-regression-with-interval-constraints/) and [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/regression-with-interval-constraints/#restriction). Post estimation, I know I can use `nlcom` to recover the original parameter.

I want to get the original parameter into my main estimation table, obtained by `esttab`. However, using `nlcom, post` adds an additional estimation instead of substituting the desired value:

```
sysuse auto, clear

est clear

nl (price = exp({lna}) * length + {c}), nolog
est store baseReg

nlcom a: exp(_b[lna:_cons]), post
est store nl

esttab *
```

which yields

```
. esttab *

--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                    price           price   
--------------------------------------------
main                                        
a                                   57.20***
                                   (4.06)   

_cons               4.047***                
                  (16.44)                   
--------------------------------------------
c                                           
_cons             -4584.9                   
                  (-1.72)                   
--------------------------------------------
N                      74              74   
--------------------------------------------
```

Instead of showing the (transformed) parameter estimate of 4.047, **and** the recovered estimate of 57.20, I want the 57.20 to be shown instead of the 4.047, as part of spec (1). Spec (2) should not appear at all.

How do I achieve this? Does this require some hack with `e(b)` and `e(V)`?

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a better solution than this, but as a quick hack, one could just pass the other coefficients without any transformations.

Here's what this would look like on the sample:

```
sysuse auto, clear

est clear

nl (price = exp({lna}) * length + {c}), nolog
est store baseReg

nlcom (lna: exp(_b[lna:_cons])) (c: _b[c:_cons]), post
est store baseReg2

esttab baseReg2
```

Note that only the last table is reported. Also, this will become cumbersome with a large number of variables, so there has to be a better way.

Result:

```
----------------------------
                      (1)   
                    price   
----------------------------
lna                 57.20***
                   (4.06)   

c                 -4584.9   
                  (-1.72)   
----------------------------
N                      74   
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```